# Changing multiple classes on scroll

Tags: javascript

I've got the following code, but can't make multiple classes change [on scroll][1]:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 )
        $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "relative");
        $(".header").css("position", "fixed");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "90px");
    else
        $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "fixed");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax. You have missing brackets. Use:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 ) {
        $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "relative");
        $(".header").css("position", "fixed");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "90px");
    } else {
        $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "fixed");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing braces:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 ) {
        $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "relative");
        $(".header").css("position", "fixed");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "90px");
    } else {
        $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "fixed");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `{}` if they are not specified `if works only for one line`

```
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 )
        {
          $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "relative");
          $(".header").css("position", "fixed");
          $("body").css("padding-top", "90px");
        }
    else
        $("#top-nav-wrapper").css("position", "fixed");
});
```